# Mostrar mensaje cuando comando arroje vacío

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

Tengo un programa que verifica si existen archivos a la fecha.
Pero quisiera que me muestre un mensaje cuando este no arroje resultado.

¿Algún comando para validar cuando el comando arroje vacío?

```
#Variables
vDay=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

cat text.log | grep $vDay
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una forma sencilla, minimalista, y en una línea de hacerlo, además de, a mi gusto, muy bonita.

```
grep -q "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" text.log && echo "Hay datos" || echo "No hay datos"
```

Lo que hace `grep` con el parámetro `-q` es no imprimir nada en el *stdout* y únicamente regresar un estado de éxito si encontró el patrón o si hubo un error, y 1 si no encontró el patrón.

Eso sobre el archivo `text.log`, por lo que no hay que hacer uso de `cat` y de un *pipe* y, al menos a mi gusto, hace menos necesario que guardes datos en una variable.

Si el estado de salida de `grep` es exitoso (o sea igual a 0), entonces se ejecuta lo que esté a la derecha del token `&&` e imprime "Hay datos", de lo contrario, si el estado de salida de grep no es exitoso (no es igual a 0), entonces no se ejecuta lo que está a la derecha del token `&&` sino lo que esté a la derecha del token `||` e imprime "No hay datos".

O sea, `<comando> && <comando si lo anterior devuelve 0> || <comando si lo anterior no devuelve 0>` lo puedes tomar como un *short-if-else* y no almacenas datos en memoria ni archivos de más.

Comment: ¿grep -q retorna éxito si hubo un error? No creo

Comment: Si, `Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred. However, if the -q or --quiet or --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred.`

Answer (score 1):

- En primer lugar, aunque no es mandatorio, puedes asignar la salida del comando a una variable con `salida=$(cat text.log | grep $vDay)`
- Luego usamos [`test`](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html) en su forma de alias `[[ ]]` para preguntar si longitud de nuestra variable es 0.

Ejemplo:

```
vDay=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
salida=$(cat text.log | grep $vDay)

if [[ -z "$salida" ]]
then
      echo "\$salida is NULL"
else
      echo "\$salida is NOT NULL"
fi
```

Comment: `cat fichero | grep patrón` se puede simplificar con `grep patrón fichero`.